# How to replace 'FEEDS' in scrapy version 2.X with 'FEED_URI & 'FEED_FORMAT'? GUI app using Python Tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter, scrapy

I am trying to learn to make a Scrapy Desktop app using Python Tk inter. So, I'm trying to run this prebuild Scrapy desktop app using Python Tkinter. While saving the output, there is an issue with the "FEEDS". The below-mentioned function does save the output file by choosing the specific extension and saving it to a specific location. This script was developed based Scrapy version up to 1.8. So in Scrapy version 2.X the **'FEED_URI & 'FEED_FORMAT'** are not working as they have been replaced with "FEEDS".

```
def execute_spider():
    if dataset_entry.get() == '' or chosen_feed not in ['CSV', 'JSON']:
        messagebox.showerror('Error', 'All entries are required')
        return
    try:
        feed_uri = f'file:///{folder_path}/{dataset_entry.get()}.{chosen_feed}'
    except:
        messagebox.showerror('Error', 'All entries are required')

    settings = project.get_project_settings()
    settings. Set('FEED_URI', feed_uri)
    settings. Set('FEED_FORMAT', chosen_feed)

    configure_logging()
    runner = CrawlerRunner(settings)
    runner.crawl(chosen_spider)

    reactor.run(installSignalHandlers=False)
```

To see the full script, you can also visit [here](https://github.com/krishnakaushik25/Web-Scraping-using-Scrapy-Tkinter-Desktop-App)

So, how can I use 'FEEDS' instead of these particular 2 lines?

```
settings. Set('FEED_URI', feed_uri)
settings. Set('FEED_FORMAT', chosen_feed)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would instead use

```
settings.set("FEEDS", {
   feed_uri: {
       'format': chosen_format,
       'encoding': 'utf8'
 }
})
```

and include any other settings that are appropriate.

Refer to the scrapy docs for available options:  [FEEDS](https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/feed-exports.html#feeds)

Comment: With this, the script is running but no output data is saved. What else I need to do?

Comment: There is probably no data saved because there was no data scraped.  If you have more questions then mark this one as complete and open a new one this time include more information like your whole script and the url you are trying to scrape and the selectors you are using and any logs you are receiving

Comment: Well please check this new question
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74294691/why-scrapy-feeds-not-saving-the-output-file