# Why scrapy "FEEDS" not saving the output file?

Tags: python, tkinter, scrapy

The purpose of this scrapy spider is to check the response status of a bunch of websites. I'm also trying to build a simple desktop GUI app using python tkinter for this spider as an experiment. This app is scraping as I needed but it is not saving the output in a file. I have asked this question previously but this time providing more details.

## spider

```
import scrapy
import pandas as pd
from twisted.internet.error import DNSLookupError


class CheckSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'check'

    def read_xl(df):
        df = pd.read_excel('url.xlsx')
        return df['url'].tolist()

    def start_requests(self):
        for value in self.read_xl():
            yield scrapy.Request(
                url=value,
                callback= self.parse,
                errback=self.parse_error
            )
        return super().start_requests()

    def parse_error(self, failure):
        if failure.check(DNSLookupError):
            request = failure.request
            yield {
                'URL': request.url,
                'Status': failure.value
            }

    def parse(self, response):
        if response.request.meta.get('redirect_urls'):
            yield {
                'URL': response.request.meta.get('redirect_urls')[0],
                'Redireted URL': response.request.url,
                'Status': response.status
            }
        else:
            yield {
                'URL': response.url,
                'Redireted URL': response.request.url,
                'Status': response.status
            }
```

## GUI (apps.py)

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import messagebox
from tkinter import filedialog
from scrapy.utils import project
from scrapy import spiderloader
from scrapy.utils.log import configure_logging
from scrapy.crawler import CrawlerRunner
from twisted.internet import reactor
import threading


def get_spiders():
    settings = project.get_project_settings()
    spider_loader = spiderloader.SpiderLoader.from_settings(settings)
    return spider_loader.list()

def get_chosen_spider(value):
    global chosen_spider
    chosen_spider = value
    return chosen_spider

def get_chosen_feed(value):
    global chosen_feed
    chosen_feed = value
    return chosen_feed

def browse_button():
    global folder_path
    folder_path = filedialog.askdirectory()
    folder_path_entry.delete(0, END)
    folder_path_entry.insert(0, folder_path)
    return folder_path

def execute_spider():
    if dataset_entry.get() == '' or chosen_feed not in ['CSV', 'JSON']:
        messagebox.showerror('Error', 'All entries are required')
        return
    try:
        feed_uri = f'file:///{folder_path}/{dataset_entry.get()}.{chosen_feed}'
    except:
        messagebox.showerror('Error', 'All entries are required')

    settings = project.get_project_settings()
    # settings.set('FEED_URI', feed_uri)
    # settings.set('FEED_TYPE', chosen_feed)
    settings.set("FEEDS", {
        f'output.{chosen_feed}': {
            'format': chosen_feed,
            'encoding': 'utf8'
        }
    })

    configure_logging()
    runner = CrawlerRunner(settings)
    runner.crawl(chosen_spider)

    reactor.run(installSignalHandlers=False)

def start_execute_thread(event):
    global execute_thread
    execute_thread = threading.Thread(target=execute_spider, daemon=True)
    execute_thread.start()
    app.after(10, check_execute_thread)

def check_execute_thread():
    if execute_thread.is_alive():
        app.after(10, check_execute_thread)


app = Tk()
# app title
app.title('Check Website Status')
# app size
app.geometry('300x200')
app.resizable(False, False)

# app label
spider_label = Label(app, text='Choose a spider')
spider_label.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky=W, pady=10, padx=10)

# Choose Spider
spider_text = StringVar(app)
spider_text.set('Choose a spider')
spiders = [spider for spider in get_spiders()]

spiders_dropdown = OptionMenu(app, spider_text, *spiders, command=get_chosen_spider)
spiders_dropdown.grid(row=0, column=1, columnspan=2)

# Feed Type
feed_label = Label(app, text='Choose a feed')
feed_label.grid(row=1, column=0, sticky=W, pady=10, padx=10)

feed_text = StringVar(app)
feed_text.set('Choose a spider')
feeds = ['CSV', 'JSON']

feed_dropdown = OptionMenu(app, feed_text, *feeds, command=get_chosen_feed)
feed_dropdown.grid(row=1, column=1, columnspan=2)

# path entry
folder_path_text = StringVar(app)
folder_path_entry = Entry(app, textvariable=folder_path_text)
folder_path_entry.grid(row=2, column=0, pady=10, padx=10)

# Dataset entry
dataset_text = StringVar(app)
dataset_entry = Entry(app, textvariable=dataset_text, width=10)
dataset_entry.grid(row=2, column=1, pady=10, padx=10)

browse_btn = Button(app, text='Browse', command=browse_button)
browse_btn.grid(row=2, column=2,)

execute_btn = Button(app,text='Execute', command=lambda: start_execute_thread(None))
execute_btn.grid(row=3, column=0, columnspan=3)

app.mainloop()
```

## Output

```
{'URL': 'https://equbot.com/our-customers/', 'Redireted URL': 'https://equbot.com/our-customers/', 'Status': 200}
2022-11-03 00:59:43 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET https://www.fincura.com/> (referer: None)
2022-11-03 00:59:43 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://www.buxtonco.com/customers>
{'URL': 'https://www.buxtonco.com/clients', 'Redireted URL': 'https://www.buxtonco.com/customers', 'Status': 200}
2022-11-03 00:59:43 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET https://www.features-analytics.com/> (referer: None)
2022-11-03 00:59:43 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://www.fincura.com/>
{'URL': 'https://www.fincura.com/', 'Redireted URL': 'https://www.fincura.com/', 'Status': 200}
2022-11-03 00:59:43 [scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.redirect] DEBUG: Redirecting (301) to <GET https://www.eventus.com/> from <GET https://www.eventussystems.com/>
2022-11-03 00:59:43 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://www.features-analytics.com/>
{'URL': 'https://www.features-analytics.com/', 'Redireted URL': 'https://www.features-analytics.com/', 'Status': 200}
2022-11-03 00:59:43 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET https://fincad.com/> (referer: None)
2022-11-03 00:59:43 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET https://www.featurespace.com/customers/> (referer: None)
2022-11-03 00:59:43 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://fincad.com/>
{'URL': 'https://fincad.com/', 'Redireted URL': 'https://fincad.com/', 'Status': 200}
2022-11-03 00:59:43 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://www.featurespace.com/customers/>
{'URL': 'https://www.featurespace.com/customers/', 'Redireted URL': 'https://www.featurespace.com/customers/', 'Status': 200}
```

Comment: Please provided a specific segment where the error throws up.

Comment: I'm trying to save the output in a CSV file but it is not creating any CSV file. This is most probably for the 'FEEDS' but I don't know how to use it in a function to execute from tkinter app

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is something wrong with your `chosen_feeds` variable. I couldn't get your app to work it kept showing a messagebox that I had to fill in all the values even though they were filled.

But I was able to get it to work once I commented out a bunch of stuff and set the hardcoded the `chosen_feeds` variable to `json` and it works with `csv` too.

---

update:

Upon further investigation, I can confirm that it is because of the `ALL_CAPS` that you are using for the `CSV` and `JSON` labels.  Scrapy requires that you use lowercase characters.

Simply setting the `chosen_feed` variable to lower case letters solves the problem.

For example:

```
def execute_spider():
    if dataset_entry.get() == '' or chosen_feed not in ['CSV', 'JSON']:
        messagebox.showerror('Error', 'All entries are required')
        return
    try:
        feed_uri = f'file:///{folder_path}/{dataset_entry.get()}.{chosen_feed}'
    except:
        messagebox.showerror('Error', 'All entries are required')
    chosen_feed = chosen_feed.lower()   # <- added this
    settings = project.get_project_settings()
    settings.set("FEEDS", {
        f'output.{chosen_feed}': {
            'format': chosen_feed,
            'encoding': 'utf8'
        }
    })

    configure_logging()
    runner = CrawlerRunner(settings)
    runner.crawl(chosen_spider)

    reactor.run(installSignalHandlers=False)
```

---

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import messagebox
from tkinter import filedialog
from scrapy.utils import project
from scrapy import spiderloader
from scrapy.utils.log import configure_logging
from scrapy.crawler import CrawlerRunner
from twisted.internet import reactor
import threading

def get_spiders():
    settings = project.get_project_settings()
    spider_loader = spiderloader.SpiderLoader.from_settings(settings)
    return spider_loader.list()

def browse_button():
    global folder_path
    folder_path = filedialog.askdirectory()
    folder_path_entry.delete(0, END)
    folder_path_entry.insert(0, folder_path)
    return folder_path

def execute_spider():
    chosen_spider = spider_text.get()
    chosen_feed = feed_text.get()
    if dataset_entry.get() == '' or chosen_feed not in ['csv', 'json']:
        messagebox.showerror('Error', 'All entries are required')
        return
    try:
        feed_uri = f'file:///{folder_path}/{dataset_entry.get()}.{chosen_feed}'
    except:
        messagebox.showerror('Error', 'All entries are required')

    settings = project.get_project_settings()
    # settings.set('FEED_URI', feed_uri)
    # settings.set('FEED_TYPE', chosen_feed)
    settings.set("FEEDS", {
        f'output.{chosen_feed}': {
            'format': chosen_feed,
            'encoding': 'utf8'
        }
    })

    configure_logging()
    runner = CrawlerRunner(settings)
    runner.crawl(chosen_spider)

    reactor.run(installSignalHandlers=False)

def start_execute_thread(event):
    global execute_thread
    execute_thread = threading.Thread(target=execute_spider, daemon=True)
    execute_thread.start()
    app.after(10, check_execute_thread)

def check_execute_thread():
    if execute_thread.is_alive():
        app.after(10, check_execute_thread)


app = Tk()
# app title
app.title('Check Website Status')
# app size
app.geometry('300x200')
app.resizable(False, False)

# app label
spider_label = Label(app, text='Choose a spider')
spider_label.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky=W, pady=10, padx=10)

# Choose Spider
spider_text = StringVar(app)
spider_text.set('Choose a spider')
spiders = [spider for spider in get_spiders()]

spiders_dropdown = OptionMenu(app, spider_text, *spiders)
spiders_dropdown.grid(row=0, column=1, columnspan=2)

# Feed Type
feed_label = Label(app, text='Choose a feed')
feed_label.grid(row=1, column=0, sticky=W, pady=10, padx=10)

feed_text = StringVar(app)
feed_text.set('Choose a feed')
feeds = ['csv', 'json']

feed_dropdown = OptionMenu(app, feed_text, *feeds)
feed_dropdown.grid(row=1, column=1, columnspan=2)

# path entry
folder_path_text = StringVar(app)
folder_path_entry = Entry(app, textvariable=folder_path_text)
folder_path_entry.grid(row=2, column=0, pady=10, padx=10)

# Dataset entry
dataset_text = StringVar(app)
dataset_entry = Entry(app, textvariable=dataset_text, width=10)
dataset_entry.grid(row=2, column=1, pady=10, padx=10)

browse_btn = Button(app, text='Browse', command=browse_button)
browse_btn.grid(row=2, column=2,)

execute_btn = Button(app,text='Execute', command=lambda: start_execute_thread(None))
execute_btn.grid(row=3, column=0, columnspan=3)

app.mainloop()
```

Comment: have you got the CSV/JSON output?

Comment: now I'm facing 2 issues. firstly, two windows are starting. One is blank. and second,
  File "D:\OneDrive\OneDrive - MSFT\scrapy_projects\project_website_checker\website_checker\website_checker\spiders\gui2.py", line 35, in execute_spider
    if dataset_entry.get() == '' or chosen_feed not in ['CSV', 'JSON']:
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'chosen_feed' referenced before assignment

Comment: @RaisulIslam  this is probably because the gui file is located in the same directory as your spiders... move it to the directory above or the base directory for the project.

Comment: I have moved the gui file to the base directory and it stopped duplicating the UI. But still getting this error   File "d:\OneDrive\OneDrive - MSFT\scrapy_projects\project_website_checker\website_checker\gui.py", line 58, in execute_spider
    if dataset_entry.get() == '' or chosen_feed not in ['CSV', 'JSON']:
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'chosen_feed' referenced before assignment

Comment: @RaisulIslam  I don't know why you are getting that error.  but I made some adjustments to your script that might help... I added the full script to the end of post

Comment: I appreciate your effort. It worked @Alexander